# reference for p-adic Stein spaces

Tags: rigid-analytic-geometry, stein-manifolds, p-adic-analysis

Hi,

I'm looking for a reference in english for p-adic Stein spaces. The usual referneces I come across are all in german.

Thanks

Comment: A negative comment: the *only* papers that I have ever attempted to read in the original German are papers of Kiehl/Bosch/Bartenwerfer from around that period. I had a German dictionary on my desk and a German mathematician friend contactable via email, and I ploughed through. I felt it "got easier" as I went along -- e.g. I had to ask what Raum meant, once, but only once.

Comment: I am pretty sure you are not going to find anything that is not written in German for the general theory.

If you want to look specifically at compact Stein spaces, there are two articles by Qing Liu (be careful if you read it, the definition he takes is different from Kiehl's: the only thing he requires is the vanishing of the higher coherent cohomology). They are not written in German, not in English either, but in French!